# Can't get Visual Studio 2013 load tests queued to controller

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

For a Visual Studio web performance testing set up, I have:

1. My local workstation running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
2. A Windows 2008 R2 server for the controller
3. Another Windows 2008 R2 server set up as a load test agent

The Windows 2008 R2 servers connect to each other fine. In Visual Studio I can go to Load Test -> Manage Controller and see the controller and the agent.

However when I have test settings with the controller, I am unable to queue any tests. The Test Results say: *Not Executed* - Test run error. With the detail being: Test run could not be executed:

> **Failed to queue test run to the controller that dcollects data and
>   diagnostics: VSCONTROLLER:6901. No such host is known.**

I've verified all service accounts have appropriate Administrator and controller group permissions as well as disabled all firewalls.

Comment: Look in the Event Log on the Test Agent and/or Test Controller machines.

Comment: Those have been checked and they note that a connection as attempted but cannot be established. When watching via procmon I can see the TCP connections to established to 6901. However the test is still unable to queue and run...

Comment: Know its a bit old now, but did you happen to get this working. Was it a problem with the hosts file?

Comment: It's a known bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2643086

Comment: @dannash - still not working on different subnets. Have to RDP into a server on the subnet with Visual Studio. This has hindered adoption.

Answer (score 3):

Check your hosts file. I had the same problem. If you have entries there your client machine sends the computer name it finds in the first entry to the controller as its name. The controller ends up querying DNS for the name it received.

So in my case, let's say my first entry is:
127.0.0.1 abcd

The test controller tries to call back to abcd.yourdomain.com and if it can't find it you get that error. If that is the case add your actual computer name as the first entry in your hosts file and the controller should be able to find it successfully (assuming your DNS is set up correctly of course).

Note that if you have no entries in your host file, the test controller will receive the correct computer name, so if that is the case you are experiencing a different issue.